# Angular resource converting Date object into String while fetching data

Tags: angularjs, date, express, angular-resource

I am using Angular resource for ajax operations in my project. I have some date fields i am converting them into JavaScript `Date()` Object at server when i am fetching the data, i am using Node js (Express js ) at server side. At client side i require this date object for [uib datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup). My Server code for date conversion is:

```
  findAndFormatDate: function (data) {

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {

      if (key.indexOf("date") !== -1 || key.indexOf("Date") !== -1) {
        data[key] = new Date(data[key]);
        if (data[key] instanceof Date) {
          console.log("Yes it is a date, and the type is ", typeof data[key]);
        }
      }

    });

    return data;

  }
```

and at server console i am getting the message **Yes it is a date, and the type is object,** but when i am getting this data at client side and checking the `typeof` this date field then it is showing `string` and i need to again convert it at client side then it is working properly, i am not able to understand why it requires two time conversion, i want to convert in only at server side so how can i avoid the conversion at client side?

Comment: I could imagine the data being sent to the server side comes *in* as a String, since that's what JSON primarily deals with, but I'm a bit confused as to why you believe you need to convert it twice.  Is the date going back to the client mangled somehow?

Comment: The fetched date field i am assigning to uib datepicker which only accepts javascript date() object, but when i am assigning it directly the date picker is not showing the date and when if i am converting again at client side then the date picker is showing the date.

Comment: @Makoto can you tell me the meaning of this format:- `"2016-10-30T18:30:00.000Z"` this is i am getting from the server but instated it should be `Mon Oct 31 2016 13:41:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.